# Large subgroups of Knuth's non-associative "group" on ${\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, computer-science, infinite-combinatorics

[Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) introduced a fast, bit-wise [approximation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394296/hamming-distance-between-ab-and-a-oplus-b-oplus-a-land-b-ll-1) to integer addition by $$(a,b) \mapsto a \, ^{\land} \, b \, ^{\land} \, ((a \text{ & } b) \ll 1)$$
where $a,b$ are given in binary and $\,^{\land}$ denotes bitwise ${\tt XOR}$, then $\text{&}$ is bitwise ${\tt AND}$, and finally $\ll 1$ denotes shifting to the left by $1$ position. (Note that $((a \text{ & } b) \ll 1)$ is used to simulate binary [carry propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_(arithmetic)).)

This can be extended in a nice way giving rise to a binary operation $\oplus:{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})\times {\cal P}(\mathbb{N}) \to {\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$. For $A \in {\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$, let $A+1 = \{a+1: a\in A\}$, and for $A, B\in {\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ we let $A \, \triangle \, B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$ be the symmetric difference. The construction $A \, \triangle \, B$ plays the role of bit-wise ${\tt XOR}$ and $A+1$ simulates the left-shift.

Then for $A,B \in {\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ we let $$A \oplus B := (A \, \triangle \, B) \, \triangle \, ((A \cap B) + 1).$$

The empty set $\emptyset \in {\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ is the neutral element, the operation is commutative, but not associative: if $A = \{0\}$ and $C = \{1\}$, then $(A \oplus A) \oplus C = \{2\}$, but $A \oplus (A \oplus C) = \emptyset$.

However, every element of ${\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ has an [inverse](https://github.com/dominiczypen/plus_approximation/blob/main/knuth_plus_approx.pdf) with respect to $\oplus$.

Let us call $U\subseteq  {\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ a *subgroup* of ${\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ if it is closed under $\oplus$ and taking inverses, and if $U$ is associative. Zorn's Lemma implies that every subgroup is contained in a maximal subgroup of ${\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ with respect to set inclusion $\subseteq$.

**Question.** Do all maximal subgroups of ${\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ have the same cardinality? And is there an uncountable subgroup of ${\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$?

(Only one of the questions needs to be fully answered for acceptance.)

Comment: Note: Already $(A+A)+(A+A) = (A+(A+(A+A)))$  seems to put strong constraints on the elements such a subgroup may contain, there might be very few.

Comment: Now it is me who is not sure whether I can correctly decrypt your sub-magma, @bof ..

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to be (I hope) more readable. By the way, there's no need to call the magma $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N),\oplus)$ a "group" in scare quotes; the standard name for such an object is [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup). If you extend the operation to $\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$, the magma $(\mathcal P(\mathbb Z),\oplus)$ is not a loop or a quasigroup, and it still has no nontrivial "subgroups", but it has a (slightly) nontrivial "subsemigroup", namely $\{\emptyset,\mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks @bof!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the suggestion in a comment by [Achim Krause](https://mathoverflow.net/users/39747/achim-krause) I will show that the only solution of the equation $(x\oplus x)\oplus(x\oplus x)=x\oplus(x\oplus(x\oplus x))$ in the magma $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N),\oplus)$ is $x=\emptyset$, whence $\{\emptyset\}$ is the only associative submagma of $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N),\oplus)$.

It will be convenient to identify an element of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ with its characteristic function as a subset of $\mathbb Z$, so that for $x\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ and $n\in\mathbb Z$ we have $x_n=1$ if $n\in x$ and $x_n=0$ if $n\notin x$; in particular $x_n=0$ for all $n\lt0$. Thus for all $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $x,y\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ we have $(x\oplus y)_n=x_n+y_n+x_{n-1}y_{n-1}$ (addition modulo $2$).

Now, for any $x\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ and any $n\in\mathbb Z$, we have
$$(x\oplus x)_n=x_n+x_n+x_{n-1}x_{n-1}=x_{n-1}$$
and
$$((x\oplus x)\oplus(x\oplus x))_n=(x\oplus x)_{n-1}=x_{n-2},$$
so that
$$((x\oplus x)\oplus(x\oplus x))_{n+2}=x_n.\tag1$$
Also
$$(x\oplus(x\oplus x))_n=x_n+x_{n-1}+x_{n-1}x_{n-2}$$
and
$$(x\oplus(x\oplus(x\oplus x)))_n=$$$$x_n+(x_n+x_{n-1}+x_{n-1}x_{n-2})+x_{n-1}(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}+x_{n-2}x_{n-3})$$$$=x_{n-1}x_{n-2}x_{n-3},$$
so that
$$(x\oplus(x\oplus(x\oplus x)))_{n+2}=x_{n+1}x_nx_{n-1}.\tag2$$
If $(x\oplus x)\oplus(x\oplus x)=x\oplus(x\oplus(x\oplus x))$, then from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have
$$x_n=((x\oplus x)\oplus(x\oplus x))_{n+2}=$$$$(x\oplus(x\oplus(x\oplus x)))_{n+2}=x_{n+1}x_nx_{n-1},$$
whence $x_n=1\implies x_{n+1}=x_{n-1}=1$, *i.e.*, $x$ is a constant function. Since $x_n=0$ for $n\lt0$, it follows that $x_n=0$ for all $n$.